# Find employees without training records

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access training database that logs training by session and topic.  The reason for the split is one session might cover multiple topics.  I'm trying to make a query that will pull which employees are missing a given topic.  I have no problem getting a query that lists what training each employee attended, however the reverse is not working.  Data model shown below:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the ***Find Unmatched* Query Wizard** in Access??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use joins to correlate employee ids to topics and then use the `not exists` operator to find employees that are missing a topic:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tblEmployees e
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   tblTrainingTopics tt
                   JOIN   tblTrainingSessions ts ON tt.sessionid = ts.id
                   JOIN   tblTrainingLog tl ON tl.session = ts.id
                   WHERE  tl.eenumber = e.eeid AND tt.topic = 'some_topic')
```

Comment: You're very close.  That gives the correct report for one topic.  I'm trying to get a report that shows all topics.  In other words person A is missing topic X and person B is missing topic Y

Comment: Replace 'some_topic' with '*' to see all topics in one report